# iptables: trying to block network access for all but specified users

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall

I am an iptables novice, and I want to block network access for all users except "user" and root. I set up iptables as follows:

```
$ sudo iptables -L OUTPUT
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             owner UID match user
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             owner UID match root
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             owner socket exists
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

I then logged in as "other" and did the following (using one of Google's IP addresses):

```
$ whoami
other
$ wget http://172.217.19.36
--2020-06-25 18:43:16--  http://172.217.19.36/
Connecting to 172.217.19.36:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/ [following]
--2020-06-25 18:43:16--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address 'www.google.com'
```

In other words, iptables let a user who is not "user" or root access Google using wget.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on EchoMike444's helpful advice, I now have the following ruleset:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner user -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner root -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner systemd-resolve -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j REJECT
```

This seems to do the trick: I can still access the outside world, other users can't, but ICMP rejection messages from rule 5 are still allowed to get through thanks to rule 4.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your rule `-m owner --socket-exists`

You can see by doing this example :

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 0 -j LOG --log-prefix UID_ROOT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 1000 -j LOG --log-prefix UID_1000
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --socket-exists -j LOG --log-prefix OWN_SOCKETS
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 1000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOG --log-prefix WILL-REJECT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

and with `iptables-save -c | grep OUTPUT` , you can see packets counters .

so with sequence you can see what's happend .

```
sudo  iptables -Z  ; 
sudo  iptables-save -c | grep OUTPUT ; 
/usr/bin/wget http://172.217.19.36 ; 
sudo  iptables-save -c | grep OUTPUT
```

and in the file /var/log/kern.log , you can a tail with this

```
tail -200f /var/log/kern.log | grep -e WILL_ -e OWN_ -e UID_ /var/log/kern.log
```

You may need to allow another user for DNS , that depends what is you current mechanism .

On regular Ubuntu you are using systemd-resolve , so you need to add the uid of `systemd-resolve` .

Comment: OK. I added that rule after reading a post that said: "When you try to access the Internet from your user, this involves at least DNS request. Userspace process requests kernel to resolve it with a function like gethostbyname(). Which makes kernel to send its own packet to the DNS server. Which becomes blocked by your iptables setup. Networking also involves ARP requests which is also originating from kernel. To resolve this you need to allow packets having sockets but no UID associated with them. This is done with --socket-exists option..." So I'll play with it & see.what happens. Thanks.

Comment: Taking that rule out, I get "unable to resolve" when I do "wget www.google.com" as myself. In my original post, I used an IP address when I was logged in as "other" because I had no DNS there either, but it was OK when I was being myself.

Comment: @Phssthpok i modified my answer to add a comment about DNS

Comment: OK, thanks. That seems to do the trick: I can do wget www.google.com, but running the same via "sudo -u other" I get "Temporary failure in name resolution." However, if I use an IP address, it hangs for 2 minutes, then says "failed: Connection timed out" and retries, rather than being rejected immediately.